# How do I set up MetaMask in a new browser on the same machine without having to dig up contract addresses for all my tokens?

Tags: metamask

I'm trying to switch the browser I use for MetaMask, though staying on the same machine. I can't find any documentation on how to do this although I would think connecting MetaMask to an existing wallet would be a common problem. It was easy enough to get MetaMask running in the new browser. I was able to add each of my accounts (though I had to enter the names for each manually; I believe if I didn't know the exactly spelling my life might have been quite difficult). But now MetaMask in my new browser doesn't detect any of my coins except the very most common ones. Is there a way to important my settings from my MetaMask config in the old browser? Or failing that, is there an efficient way to get a list of the addresses for all my existing tokens so I can add them quickly? I don't see where MetaMask makes it possible for me to get this information in the UI.

In my research the closest thing I found to an answer was [this page](https://community.metamask.io/t/recovering-and-backing-up-your-accounts-tokens/3687) which talks about storing information your coins in a JSON file, but I don't see where it tells you how to get the information into the JSON file in the first place.

Comment: Hi there. When you say you had to type the names in manually, do you mean the hexadecimal address?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks, no just I entered the addresses via their human-friendly names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:

> Or failing that, is there an efficient way to get a list of the addresses for all my existing tokens so I can add them quickly?

Etherscan's Token Holdings page for your account:

```
https://etherscan.io/tokenholdings?a=<account_address>
```